# Python letter frequency mapping

Tags: python

I have a Python script that reads in a encrypted text file and decrypts it in various ways. The last 2 options I am trying to add are to map out the most frequent letters of the file and the most frequent letters in the English language.

Here are my previous functions that display frequency:

```
def functOne:
    Crypt = input("what file would you like to select? ")
    filehandle = open(Crypt, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            print(char, count)

def FunctTwo: 
    print "Relative letter Freq of letters in English Language A-Z; ENGLISH = (0.0749, 0.0129, 0.0354, 0.0362, 0.1400, 0.0218, 0.0174, 0.0422, 0.0665, 0.0027, 0.0047, 0.0357, 0.0339, 0.0674, 0.0737, 0.0243, 0.0026, 0.0614, 0.0695, 0.0985, 0.0300, 0.0116, 0.0169, 0.0028, 0.0164, 0.0004)"
```

Here's the description of what I need to do for the next two:

> Function 3:
>
> Map the most frequent letter in text to the most frequent in the English language in descending order.
>
> `[letter in cryptogram] -> [letter in english language]`
>
> Function 4:
>
> Allow user to manually edit frequency maps

How would I go about doing this? I'm kinda lost on the mapping part, at least combing the two frequencies and allow editing.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to turn your code into actual valid Python code. For example, your functions have to be defined with a list of arguments.

Then, you have to do is *return* values rather than just printing them.

Also, you don't want a string representation of a tuple of frequencies, but an actual tuple of them that you can use.

And finally, you're going to have to put the two collections into some kind of format that can be compared. `ENGLISH` is just a sequence of 26 frequencies; the value computed by `functOne` is a sequence of up to 26 (letter, count) pairs in descending order of frequency. But really, we don't need the counts or the frequencies at all; we just need the letters in descending order of frequency.

In fact, if you look at it, `functTwo` is completely unnecessary—it's effectively computing a constant, so you might as well just do that at module level.

While we're at it, I'd reorganize functOne so it takes the input as an argument. And close the file instead of leaking it. And give the functions meaningful names.

```
def count_letters(data):
    data = data.upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    return [char for char, count in char_counter.most_common()]

english_freqs = (0.0749, 0.0129, 0.0354, 0.0362, 0.1400, 0.0218, 0.0174, 
                 0.0422, 0.0665, 0.0027, 0.0047, 0.0357, 0.0339, 0.0674, 
                 0.0737, 0.0243, 0.0026, 0.0614, 0.0695, 0.0985, 0.0300, 
                 0.0116, 0.0169, 0.0028, 0.0164, 0.0004)
pairs = zip(english_freqs, string.ascii_uppercase)
english_letters = [char for count, char in sorted(pairs, reversed=True)]

def decrypt(data):
    input_letters = count_letters(data)
    return {input_letter: english_letter
           for input_datum, english_datum in zip(input_letters, english_letters)}

crypt = input("what file would you like to select? ")
with open(crypt, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
mapping = decrypt(data)
```

For the editing feature… you'll have to design what you want the interface to be, before you can implement it. But presumably you're going to edit the `english_freqs` object (which means you may want to use a `list` instead of a `tuple`) and rebuild `english_letters` from it (which means you may want that in a function after all).